# Extra keyboard keys (F13-F24+extras) not working under Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard

I'm trying to make Linux recognize some weird keys on this keyboard, (mainly in KDE), which happens to be a Unicomp PC 122 with the extra keys and a custom firmware which sends special codes down the wire, in accordance with https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/hut1_2.pdf higher F key notes. However, in evtest or showkeys, nothing is registered when I press the extra keys, nor do they show in /dev/input logs. The only reason I know they exist is that when running usbhid-dump it shows the keys and their special codes.
Now, I haven't actually tried anything for fixing this, as I'm not sure where to start.
Finally, here's the dump of usbhid-dump as I press all the special keys, including the non-function ones at the end.

````
 00 00 68 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790710.397458
 00 00 69 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790710.773319
 00 00 6A 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790711.129266
 00 00 6B 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790711.467295
 00 00 6C 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790711.815437
 00 00 6D 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790712.159416
 00 00 6E 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790712.461473
 00 00 6F 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790712.793283
 00 00 70 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790713.103244
 00 00 71 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790713.415390
 00 00 72 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790713.693236
 00 00 73 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790714.327268
 00 00 76 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790714.625209
 00 00 77 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790714.957205
 00 00 7C 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790715.267203
 00 00 7D 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790715.595238
 00 00 79 00 00 00 00 00
003:003:000:STREAM             1646790715.897201
 00 00 78 00 00 00 00 00```
````

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck and what is your actual question?

Comment: @mashuptwice Actual question: How do I make Linux recognize the higher keys, mostly in KDE. What I've tried: nothing, as I've not a clue where to start.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes

Comment: If they don't even have scan codes, most likely they require a driver to be written and added to the kernel to work.